# Configure makefile to run on file change

Tags: make

Is there a way to run `make` automatically when a file changes? I'm on a Mac. Non-polling would be best but I'll accept polling too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mac OS X has an API called [FSEvents](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/FSEvents_ProgGuide/) that lets you monitor directories for changes, but not individual files.

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a way to run a background service that polls the MD5 or something of the file that will change and then runs make. I am inclined to say that unless you purposely trip some trigger when changing the file, there is no way to do it without polling though. Sorry.