# Automatically `make` when dependencies change

Tags: make, dependencies

Is there a way to have make automatically run when you edit one of the files needed for the build?

Related question: [Configure makefile to run on file change](https://superuser.com/questions/293357/configure-makefile-to-run-on-file-change), but that only has an answer for Mac OS X - I'd like a more general solution if possible (though I'm actually aiming for linux).

Answer (score 4):

There isn't a general solution – each OS has its own file monitoring API. On Mac OS X it is FSEvents, on Linux – inotify or fanotify, on BSDs – kqueue.

On Linux, you could use *incron* or write a script using *inotifywait*:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
inotifywait -r -m -q -e close_write ~/project \
| while read path event file; do
    if case $file in
        autogenerated.h)   false;;   # ignore a specific file to avoid loops
        *.c|*.h|Makefile)  true;;    # watch all .c, .h files, the Makefile
        *)                 false;;   # ignore all other files to avoid loops
    esac; then                       # (specifically, you MUST ignore auto-
        (cd ~/project && make)       # -generated files)
    fi
done
```